# Touchend not firing after touchmove on Android 4.x?

Tags: javascript, android, touch, dom-events, mobile-browser

I am writing some code with Javascript just like this:

```
    var el = document.getElementById('some-div');
    el.ontouchstart = function(e){
            el.innerHTML = "touch start";
    };
    el.ontouchend = function(e){
            el.innerHTML = "touch end";
    };
    el.ontouchmove = function(e){
            el.innerHTML = "touch moved";
    };
```

This code work fine on iOS/Safari and Android 2.x.x . On Android 4.x (I tried 4.0.4 & 4.1) , touchend not firing after touchmove. If I tap the screen, don't move my finger, touchend will be fired.

How to fix this?

This is a bug of Chrome, the detail is here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152913

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you call e.preventDefault() in touchstart or touchmove it will stop the event being soaked up before it hits your ontouchend handler. I dont have a device here to try it on right now though :)