# How to catch touchend after touchmove?

Tags: android, touchesmoved

as I find out this is a [bug in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315052/touchend-not-firing-after-touchmove-on-android-4-x) but it was in 2013. So is it possible to catch touchend after touchmove + preventdefault now in 2015? 
I try to solve it this way:
`.on('mouseup  touchend touchcancel', endDrag);`
but it does not work. Can you help me please?

Comment: Did you manage to find a work around??I tried to use the e.preventDefault() and it still doesnt work.

Comment: I tried to use Hammer.js and vmouseup as well, both of those didnt work either nor does e.preventDefault() as some has suggested.